# Developer tools for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, macos

Do you know of software like MS Visual Studio for Mac ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a free suite of tools called [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) which you can download from [Apple's developer site](http://developer.apple.com). It gives you an IDE, all the different compilers, a bunch of tools, etc.

Comment: It should be on the install DVD as well; not necessarily the very latest version, but a good start if your connection is slow :)

Comment: @John: true - it may even be in Applications/Installers - but it's a bit of a waste of time installing an older version and then finding that you really wanted the latest version from developer.apple.com. Of course it may still be worth it, e.g. if you have a slow internet connection.

Comment: Note, this is no longer free: cost $5

Comment: You can still get Xcode 3.2.6 for free - only Xcode 4 costs. Personally I'm still using Xcode 3.2.6 as I find Xcode 4 too buggy and awkward to use.

Answer (score 1):

For mono development: http://monodevelop.com/. Assuming thats what you mean by visual studio and using .NET.

For native mac apps XCode: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html.